# Windows Store Apps ListView DataTemplate

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have a listview in my Windows store app:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lView" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="586" Margin="74.714,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="741"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextListMailFolderTemplate}"/>
```

and a data template for this listview:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextListMailFolderTemplate">
        <Grid Width="280">
            <TextBlock Text="some text" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light" 
               Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In C# code, I'm using this as a source for listview:

```
 List<string> GridViewData = new List<string>();
 lView.ItemsSource = GridViewData;
```

My problem is: when I use listview without the template, all data from GridViewData is displayed in listview. But when I use DataTemplate, in each listview item is text "some text" like it is defined in template. But I want to use template, and in each item of listview show data from GridViewData.  Can somebody help me please, how to do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text binding in your DataTemplate should be something like this:

```
Text="{Binding}"
```

Here is the full DataTemplate code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextListMailFolderTemplate">
   <Grid Width="280">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light" 
                 Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
      </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```